# Nested Set Query to retrieve all ancestors of each node

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, nested-sets

I have a MySQL query that I thought was working fine to retrieve all the ancestors of each node, starting from the top node, down to its immediate node. However when I added a 5th level to the nested set, it broke.

Below are example tables, queries and SQL Fiddles:

**Four Level Nested Set:**

```
CREATE TABLE Tree
(title varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
 `tree` int,
 `left` int,
 `right` int);

INSERT Tree
VALUES
("Food", 1, 1, 18),
('Fruit', 1, 2, 11),
('Red', 1, 3, 6),
('Cherry', 1, 4, 5),
('Yellow', 1, 7, 10),
('Banana', 1, 8, 9),
('Meat', 1, 12, 17),
('Beef', 1, 13, 14),
('Pork', 1, 15, 16);
```

The Query:

```
SELECT t0.title node
      ,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t2.title)
                    FROM Tree t2
                    WHERE t2.left<t0.left AND t2.right>t0.right
                    ORDER BY t2.left) ancestors
FROM Tree t0
GROUP BY t0.title;
```

The returned result for node `Banana` is `Food,Fruit,Yellow` - Perfect. You can see this here [SQL Fiddle - 4 Levels](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/351b0/1)

When I run the same query on the 5 level table below, the 5th level nodes come back in the wrong order:

```
CREATE TABLE Tree
(title varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
 `tree` int,
 `left` int,
 `right` int);

INSERT Tree
VALUES
("Food", 1, 1, 24),
('Fruit', 1, 2, 13),
('Red', 1, 3, 8),
('Cherry', 1, 4, 7),
('Cherry_pie', 1, 5, 6),
('Yellow', 1, 9, 12),
('Banana', 1, 10, 11),
('Meat', 1, 14, 23),
('Beef', 1, 15, 16),
('Pork', 1, 17, 22),
('Bacon', 1, 18, 21),
('Bacon_Sandwich', 1, 19, 20);
```

The returned result for `Bacon_Sandwich` is `Bacon,Food,Meat,Pork` which is not the right order, it should be `Food,Meat,Pork,Bacon` - You can see this here [SQL Fiddle - 5 Levels](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be6153/1)

I am not sure what is happening because I don't really understand subqueries well enough. Can anyone shed any light on this?

**EDIT AFTER INVESTIGATION:**

Woah!! Looks like writing all this out and reading up about ordering with `GROUP_CONCAT` gave me some inspiration.

Adding `ORDER BY` to the actual `GROUP_CONCAT` function and removing from the end of the subquery solved the issue. I now receive `Food,Meat,Pork,Bacon` for the node `Bacon_Sandwich`

```
SELECT t0.title node
      ,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t2.title ORDER BY t2.left)
                    FROM Tree t2
                    WHERE t2.left<t0.left AND t2.right>t0.right
                    ) ancestors
FROM Tree t0
GROUP BY t0.title;
```

I still have no idea why though. Having `ORDER BY` at the end of the subquery works for 4 levels but not for 5?!?!

If someone could explain what the issue is and why moving the `ORDER BY` fixes it, I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First it's important to understand that you have an [implicit `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

> If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.

To make the point more understandable I'll leave out subqueries and reduce the problem to the banana. Banana is the set [10, 11]. The correct sorted ancestors are those:

```
SELECT "banana" as node, GROUP_CONCAT(title ORDER by `left`)
  FROM Tree WHERE `left` < 10 AND `right` > 11
  GROUP BY node;
```

The `ORDER BY` must be in `GROUP_CONCAT()` as you want the aggregation function to sort. `ORDER BY` outside sorts by the aggregated results (i.e. the result of `GROUP_CONCAT()`). The fact that it worked until level 4 is just luck. `ORDER BY` has no effect on an aggregate function. You would get the same results with or without the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(title)
  FROM Tree WHERE `left` < 10 AND `right` > 11
  /* ORDER BY `left` */
```

---

It might help to understand what 
`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(title ORDER BY left) FROM Tree WHERE … ORDER BY left` does:

1. Get a selection (`WHERE`) which results in three rows in an undefined order:

   ```
   ("Food")
   ("Yellow")
   ("Fruit")
   ```
2. Aggregate the result into one row (implicit `GROUP BY`) in order to be able to use an aggregate function:

   ```
   (("Food","Yellow", "Fruit"))
   ```
3. Fire the aggregate function (`GROUP_CONCAT(title, ORDER BY link)`) on it. I.e. order by link and then concatenate:

   ```
   ("Food,Fruit,Yellow")
   ```
4. And now finally it sorts that result (`ORDER BY`). As it's only one row, sorting changes nothing.

   ```
   ("Food,Fruit,Yellow")
   ```

Comment: Yeah I understand how the `GROUP_CONCAT()` works, I just assumed it did it's thing after the entire query was run, which would have ordered the results with the `ORDER BY` at the end.  To be honest I am still not really sure why this is the case. Surely the ONLY way `GROUP_CONCAT()` knows WHAT to concatenate, is by the `SELECT` query. And the `SELECT` query has `ORDER BY` in it, so it should return what to `concatenate` in order?!?!? I am obviously missing something.....? Just to be clear, I know that `GROUP_CONCAT()` is concatenating the results in to one row... that is not my confusion..

Comment: I think you are missing the point about aggregation. I intentionally put a `GROUP BY` into my query. `GROUP_CONCAT()` is not operating on selected fields, it's operating on the grouped fields. You're query (without the `GROUP BY`) is just a shortcut for a `GROUP BY` query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44957/discussion-between-markus-malkusch-and-superphonic)

Answer (score 4):

You can get the result using `JOIN` or `SUB-QUERY`.

**Using JOIN:**

```
SELECT t0.title node, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.title ORDER BY t2.left) ancestors 
FROM Tree t0
LEFT JOIN Tree t2 ON t2.left < t0.left AND t2.right > t0.right
GROUP BY t0.title;
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be6153/19)

**Using SUB-QUERY:**

```
SELECT t0.title node, 
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t2.title ORDER BY t2.left)
       FROM Tree t2 WHERE t2.left<t0.left AND t2.right>t0.right) ancestors
FROM Tree t0
GROUP BY t0.title;
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be6153/20)

**OUTPUT**

```
|           NODE |             ANCESTORS |
|----------------|-----------------------|
|          Bacon |        Food,Meat,Pork |
| Bacon_Sandwich |  Food,Meat,Pork,Bacon |
|         Banana |     Food,Fruit,Yellow |
|           Beef |             Food,Meat |
|         Cherry |        Food,Fruit,Red |
|     Cherry_pie | Food,Fruit,Red,Cherry |
|           Food |                (null) |
|          Fruit |                  Food |
|           Meat |                  Food |
|           Pork |             Food,Meat |
|            Red |            Food,Fruit |
|         Yellow |            Food,Fruit |
```

In your sub query you had used `ORDER BY` after `WHERE` clause which won't affect the output. By default [**GROUP_CONCAT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function will orders the output string in ascending order of column value. It won't consider you explicit ORDER BY clause.

If you check your output of first query which returns the data in ascending order of **title** column. So the returned result for node `Banana` is `Food,Fruit,Yellow`.

But in your second result for `Bacon_Sandwich` is `Bacon,Food,Meat,Pork` because in ascending order `Bacon` comes first than `Food` will come.

If you want to order the result based on `left` column than you have to specify `ORDER BY` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function as above. Check my both queries.

I prefer that you use `JOIN` instead of `SUB-QUERY` for improving performance.

Comment: I was certain I left a comment which points you to the manual. So again: [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is not sorting at all by default.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation.